# How can i inspect variable names of a SAS dataset in Unix shell?

Tags: shell, sas

I have a big dataset (about 1G) in .sas7bdat format, and would like to know what are the variable names in it on Mac shell. Is there any possible ways to inspect the variable names easily?

I have no knowledge of SAS and also don't have a version of it for Mac. 
I tried vi, but it was totally a mess up..
I have thought about using r to load and see it, but it is just to big for r to load it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Base SAS install on your Unix server? if yes, then you can write a sas program with .sas extension(prog1.sas) using vi editor with below code:

proc contents data= Datasetname; 
run;

& then can run sas program at unix command level as
SAS prog1.sas.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this via the unix system. You could try a Python package but you might run out of memory there as well.

You can get the SAS viewer to view the dataset or try the SAS University Edition if your usage makes sense according to the licensing.

FYI - 1GB wouldn't be considered a big dataset in general for SAS.

SAS Viewer - allows viewing, sorting, filtering of SAS datasets.
http://support.sas.com/software/products/univiewer/

SAS UE http://www.sas.com/en_ca/software/university-edition.html

Comment: There is a Python package here that claims to be able to print header information: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sas7bdat